# Get the redirected php page name in AJAX call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

In the following code segment, if the requested "profile.php" redirects to another page like "login.php"., how to identify it.

```
x=new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET","profile.php",true);
x.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(x.readyState==4&&x.status==200)
{
alert("Requested url(profile.php) is loaded");
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=x.responseText;
}
}
```

We get the contents of the page via responseText member, is it possible to get the url or file name of the object requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(x.status>300 && x.status<400) alert(x.getResponseHeader("Location"));
```

[More about status meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_response_codes)